# Changing subscription topic in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to test changing subscription topic in Kafka, so I coded like this.

```
for (int count = 0; count < 30000; count++) {
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("test1"));
        consumer.unsubscribe();

        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("test2"));
        ConsumerRecords<String, Integer> records = consumer.poll(100);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, Integer> record : records) {
            String msgString = String.format("key:%s, value:%d, partition:%d offset:%d",
                    record.key(), record.value(), record.partition(), record.offset());
            System.out.println(msgString);
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But data is either not polled, or only partially polled. How can I fix it?

Comment: Yes, data **within the same consumer group** will always be polled partially up to `30000` times since that is what you have ooded. What exactly did you want to happen? Also, why `subscribe("test")` if you are just going to immediately unsubscribe it?

Comment: It's just code for another project. I want to make a program in which a consumer subscribes to a topic and receives a specific message, fetching the message contained in another topic. It can be said to be a kind of triggering. Should I go the other way?

Comment: There isn't really a way to "receive a specific message" unless you know its exact offset. Otherwise, you are polling a (partial) batch of many messages, regardless of the subscription status. Not sure what you mean "other way", but my point was that if you unsubscribe without first polling, there is no need to subscribe in the first place

Comment: Sorry, the code is just for test. My plan was to subscribe to the test1 topic, and when a specific message arrives in the test1 topic, the messages in the test2 topic are fetched. So, as a test, I wrote a code to change the subscription topic, but it doesn't work.

Comment: _when a specific message arrives in test1_ - Then you must poll after subscribing to test1, like I said, and wait for that message using some conditional statement. Only then should you switch topics. Alternatively, sounds like you're trying to join two topics, which you'd be better off using kstreams

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try it.